# Is the function an entire function?

Tags: derivatives, entire-functions

Is the following an entire function? (Here $z\in \mathbb{C}$)
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!}z^{3n}$$

($***$) So, here I first note that the function is a sum of powers of $z$. Now if I show that the sum converges for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, the problem will be solved, right?

Using ratio test i get $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2z}{n+1}$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$, showing that the function converges. The only problem is that is my statement $(***)$ correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is entire sum?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan Sorry, I changed it...its entire function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you are not using the right way to calculate the radius of convergence. First you need to get it right what $a_n$ means: it is always the coefficient of the $n$-th power term and not anything else, so in your case it should be $a_{3n}=2^n/n!$ and the others are all zero. This also means that d'Alembert ratio test isn't immediately applicable here.

However you can always use Cauchy test even if there are many zero coefficients involved, as Cauchy test only cares about the upper limit instead of the limit itself, hence unaffected by  zero coefficients in between at all: 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^\frac1n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_{3n})^\frac1{3n}=\cdots=0. $$
which shows that the RoC is infinity.

Comment: You are 100% correct in using Cauchy test...but for the last hour I had been going through the Ratio test article in Wikipedia. Now what I understand is that $z$ is a constant wrt $n$. So for any given $z$ I can take $z^{3n}$ as constant and apply the ratio test. Wikipedia doesn't mention anything about coefficients of n-th power terms. $a_n$ is just the term inside the summation but then again it doesn't give any example with complex numbers. It will help if you can site any sources regarding what you said about coefficients of $n$-th powers. Thanks for your work.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty by $n$-th power term I mean $a_nz^n$. What I tried to say is that we usually don't want to involve the variable $z$ in computing the RoC, instead, we want to directly deal with the coefficients. So in this case we must write the power series in its standard form, i.e., $a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$, so that one may *directly* apply one of those canonical methods (Cauchy, d'Alembert etc) computing RoC without any modification.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty of course, if you fix $z$ and then use ratio test to test the convergence at this very point, it's also fine, since at last you are left with a rather simple ratio $a_{n+1}/a_{n}=2z^3/(n+1)$ which clearly goes to $0$. So you can conclude that it converges everywhere hence RoC=infinity. This's absolutely fine. (I'm sorry that I perhaps didn't read your question carefully and missed the point of your method.)

Answer (score 1):

The function defined by the sum is entire, yes. For this, it suffices to check that the radius of convergence is infinite (which you have done); the result then follows as this implies that the power series is uniformly convergent everywhere.

Comment: So when I noted that the function is a sum of powers of $z$, that was necessary, right? And my answer is complete, right?